# Not able to install Eclipse Hono through Helm - error - failed to download "eclipse-iot/hono (hint: running `helm repo update may help)

Tags: eclipse-hono

I am trying to install Eclipse Hono using Helm and have the latest Helm version 3.3.0 installed in the system. I tried to follow the instructions from here - https://github.com/eclipse/packages/tree/master/charts/hono

I created the hono namespace with command -

> minikube kubectl create namespace hono

And then tried to install hono with this command -

> helm install --dependency-update -n hono eclipse-hono eclipse-iot/hono

but I got this error -
**Error: failed to download "eclipse-iot/hono" (hint: running `helm repo update` may help)**

I had searched for solutions related to this error and read that the chart repository should be added first. what is the name of the chart repository for eclipse hono?
Basically I want to know what I could be missing so that hono can be installed on my system or if there is an alternate method to install hono successfully on my local system. I have minikube version: v1.12.3 and windows version 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should follow the instructions provided on the [IoT Packages project page](https://www.eclipse.org/packages/prereqs/#helm).

After that you should do a `helm repo update`. The `helm install` command should then be able to download the chart successfully.

Comment: Thanks, it got installed after running - helm repo add eclipse-iot https://eclipse.org/packages/charts